# Testing perceived performance

Tags: performance, user-experience

I recently got a shiny new development workstation.  The only disadvantage of this is that the desktop apps I'm developing now run very, very fast, and so I fear that parts of the code that would be annoyingly slow on end users' machines will go unnoticed during my testing.

Is there a good way to slow down an application for testing?  I've tried searching around, but all of the results I've been able to find seem pretty fiddly to set up (e.g., manually setting up a high-priority CPU-bound task on the same CPU core as the target app, or running a background process that rapidly interrupts and resumes the target app), and I don't know if the end result is actually a good representation of running on a slower computer (with its slower CPU, slower RAM, slower disk I/O...).

I don't think that this is a job for a profiler; I'm interested in the user's perception of end-to-end performance rather than in where the time goes for particular operations.

Comment: Just press the turbo button to halve your CPU clock speed. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd get an old used crappy computer that is typical of what the users have and test on that. It should be cheap and you will see pretty fast how bad things are.

Answer (score 5):

setup a virtual machine, give in as little ram as needed and also you can have it use 1,2 or more CPUs. I like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) myself install your app and test with different RAM configs

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to deal with this is through proper end-user testing, i.e. get yourself a "typical" system for testing and use that to identify any perceptible performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out either [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) or [VMWare Player/Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/), load an OS onto it, and then throttle back the resources.  I know that with any of those tools you can reduce the memory to whatever you'd like.  You can also specify the number of cores you want to use.  You *might* even be able to adjust the clock speed in VMWare Workstation... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted SQLMenace's answer, but, I also think that profiling needs to be mentioned, no matter how quickly the code is executing - you'll still see what's taking the most time. If you find yourself with some free time, I think profiling and investigating the results is a good way to spend it.